# Write formally: The set of all increasing functions of real numbers - quantifiers

Tags: calculus, functions, elementary-set-theory

Write formally: The set of all increasing functions of real numbers 
I attempted to solve this problem and came up with two solutions, but I am not sure which version is good:
$$\{f(x)|(\forall m,n)(m,n \in \mathbb R \land m>n \land f(m) > f(n)\}$$
or
$$\{f(x)|(\forall m,n)((m,n \in \mathbb R \land m>n) \Rightarrow f(m) > f(n)\}$$
Which one of them works better?

Comment: The first set of functions is empty. In the second set, you say that "If $m,n\in\mathbb{R}$ and $m>n,$ then $f(m)>f(n),$ so if $m\leq n,$ the statement evaluates to true (since the antecedent is false). In the first set, you have an intersection, so this whole statement could only be satisfied if for every $m,n\in\mathbb{R},$ $m>n,$ which is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second wording is close, but should use two-way implication.

$$\{f(x)|(∀m,n \in \mathbb R, m>n \iff f(m)>f(n)\}$$

Answer (score 1):

Both are off a little bit...  How about  $\{f \vert y\gt x\implies  f (y)\gt f (x)  ,\forall   x,y \in \mathbb R\} $